# How to place a Hyperlink above a picture while centered?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get a hyper link to be centered above a picture. I tried using a div class tag to center it, but they won't allow pixels.

```
 <a href="ex.html"> HOMEPAGE </a><img src="1.jpg width="300" height="300" />
```

This is what it looks like after I run it:

[image: screenshot]

I want the hyperlink to line up in the middle of the picture.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. Also, who's "they"?

Answer (score 2):

If you add a `text-align: center` to the container element you will get what you want:

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="ex.html">HOMEPAGE</a><br />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/s7e/ffe" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A Container Approach with CSS

CSS:

```
.imagecontainer {
  width:300px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
<a href="link">
Some text
</a>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Domestic_goat_kid_in_capeweed.jpg" width=300/>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ProIcons/L5gmrcpq/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the element DIV, setting the width to 300 pixels just like your image and CSS to align the link to center:

```html
<div>
 <div style="width: 300px; text-align: center"><a href="ex.html"> HOMEPAGE </a></div>
 <div><img src="1.jpg width="300" height="300" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the other answers before posting this one?